# Extracting a portion of the a href path using Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm needing to extract a portion of an href attribute using javascript.

I've come up with a solution, but I'm not sure it's the best way. Below is my sample code. I've got a variable with the complete href path -- and all I'm interesting in extracting is the "Subcategory-Foobaz" portion.

*I can assume it will always be sandwiched between the 2nd "/" and the "?"*.

I'm terrible with Regex, so I came up with what seems like a hokie solution using 2 "splits".

```
var path = "/Category-Foobar/Subcategory-Foobaz?cm_sp=a-bunch-of-junk-i-dont-care-about";
var subcat = path.split("/")[2].split("?")[0];
console.log(subcat);
```

Is this horrible?  How would you do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var path = "/Category-Foobar/Subcategory-Foobaz?cm_sp=a-bunch-of-junk-i-dont-care-about";
var subcat = path.split("/").pop().split("?")[0];
console.log(subcat);
```

Just a small change; use pop() to get the last element no matter how many /'s you have in your string

Answer (score 0):

```
re      = /\/[^\/]+\/([^?]+)/;
str     = '/Category-Foobar/Subcategory-Foobaz?cm_sp=a-bunch-of-junk-i-dont-care-about';
matches = str.match(re);
console.log(matches);
```